# Total WS response time for multiple requests using CURL

Tags: web-services, curl, ksh

I try to run 100 requests for some Web Service via ksh script with:
 -w "total_time: %{time_total} variable. **How can i count total time for all 100 requests ?**

```
timez=0
for i in {1..100}
do
result = $(curl -s -i  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Input}": -w "total_time: %{time_total}" http//z888/zzzz/aaa/geteeeee) 

done
```

Comment: Start with `timez=$SECONDS`.  End with `dt=$((SECONDS-timez))`.

Comment: Remove the spaces around the `=`